# Disable category RSS Feeds on Wordpress blog with PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, rss

I have a Wordpress powered site and I would like to know how to disable all category based RSS feeds with PHP or even mod-rewrite if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should spend some time in the word press documentation

[disable Rss](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-rss/)

More [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page)

Comment: I didn't want to install a plugin, but instead write it myself.  I actually figured it out after I posted my question.  FAIL, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
   function check_the_feed() {
    if ( is_category() )
        wp_die( __('No feed available, please visit our homepage!') );
}
add_action('do_feed', 'check_the_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'check_the_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'check_the_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'check_the_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'check_the_feed', 1);
```